# Resultados do Google Search + Delphi 10.2 Tokyo

Tags: delphi, api, google

Procurei por *APIs* do Google para criar um código que mostre os resultados do Google em aplicações *Delphi 10.2 Tokyo*, porém não encontrei *APIs* recentes.

Preciso do seguinte, o usuário digita em um `Edit` o termo que deseja pesquisar e em um `Listview` ele visualiza os resultados com o termo que ele inseriu.

[image: Resultados do Google em aplicações Delphi]

Algo similar a essa imagem.

Várias cópias do programa serão distribuídas, por isso não posso ter limite em buscas.

Alguém já mexeu com alguma API ou precisou adicionar essa funcionalidade?

Comment: Recomendo a leitura, https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/introduction, acredito que vá te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como já referiu o @David deveria dar uma leitura no [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview), é uma ajuda bastante boa. Tem ainda uma segunda opção que é usar um componente, deixo ainda o exemplo de um [Cloud Pack](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/cloudpack.asp) que pertence a empresa [tmssoftware](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/). Este `Package` está disponível para a versão *RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo* e além da consulta google tem muitos outros componentes que se pode ainda usar.